# UIView.animate don't work if i update a UItextView - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'm new in Swift programming. I have a problem with an animation of a view when i try to change the text of a UITextView.

This is a method that is triggered from a button that is in the main view. `self.parkingMenuTittle` is a UITextView that i also have in the main view. When the button is triggered I want to change the text and set the view height to the `ycomponent` variable that my code has, but the view instead of doing that, goes to the original size. If I don't update the UITextView text my animation works just fine.

```
@objc func seeMore(_ sender: UIButton){
    self.parkingMenuTittle.text = "test"

    UIView.animate(
    withDuration: 0.2,
    animations: {
        let frame = self.view.frame
        let ycomponent = UIScreen.main.bounds.height-300
        self.view.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: ycomponent, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
    },completion: { (finished: Bool) in
        //Code
    })
}
```

I also tried to put the text in the completion block but don't work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think the issue is happening because you are changing the frame of the view. If you want to change the height of the view, you can just update according constraint for that.

Comment: you are changing your Y in frame instead of height in this line `self.view.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: ycomponent, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)`i think the solution to your problem is changing that line to this one `self.view.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.origin.y, width: frame.width, height: ycomponent)`

Comment: Didn't work, same behavior. It seems that when i update anything on any view, the animation don't work, the strange is that if i update the duration time, my view goes to the original position with that duration, that means that it's working something right(?).